# How to get form html() via jQuery including <form></form> tag?

Tags: html, forms, tags

I want to display my **form** html content into a textarea which allows the user to edit form elements via user interface. Here is my form,

```
<form name="myform" action="abc.php">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="2"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="input" value="My Name" />
</form>
```

I tried below code, but it display's the form elements only (not includes the form tag).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('a').on('click', function() { 
        $("input,select,textarea").each(function() {
           if($(this).is("[type='checkbox']") || $(this).is("[type='checkbox']")) {
             $(this).attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));
           }
           else {
              $(this).attr("value", $(this).val()); 
           }
        });
        alert($('form').html());
    });
});
</script>
```

Above code alerts an output like below,

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="2"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="input" value="My Name" />
```

But I need an output like below,

```
<form name="myform" action="abc.php">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="2"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="input" value="My Name" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you can use these function for form `$("form").clone().appendTo("body");` else use

```
<div id='formdiv1'>
<form name="myform" action="abc.php">
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="2"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="input" value="My Name" />
</form>
</div>

alert($('#formdiv1').html());
```